# Проблема с ботом тг

Tags: python, aiogram

такая проблема, ну как проблема, наткнулся на одного бота, который работает просто молниеносно!

Когда я нажал старт в боте - я не понял как он мне дал ответ, раньше я никогда не видел такого, после нажатия старт или любой другой команды - бот отвечает прям сразу!!!

Да, в основном все боты сразу отвечают, но этот бот не так работает, вот я и решил копать, от чего зависит скорость ответа телеграм бота на aiogram?

На кворке нашел человека, он показал своего бота - и он так-же быстро отвечал, дал ему запустить на своем пк своего "эхо бота" так он не отвечал так-же быстро, в чем может быть проблема?

Бот работает через пуллинг!

Не знаю можно ли размещать тут логин бота, который меня так вдохновил своей скоростью(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Скорость взаимодействия с ботом напрямую зависит от интернета и ресурсов компьютера. Больше всего указанный вами бот работает на удаленном сервере/vps, где большая скорость интернета, поэтому и ответ молниеносный.